# Python - Problemas para cargar datos de una lista a excel

Tags: python, excel

Estoy tratando de cargar a una hoja de cálculo de excel una lista `

```
    celda = 8
    contador = 0
    aux = 0
    for materia in self.subjects_array:
        print(materia)
        contador += 1
        hola = celda + contador
        datos['A{0}'.format(hola)] = materia
```

Sin embargo, a la hora del llenado me está omitiendo la última materia por llenar, al imprimir la lista, lo imprime sin problemas

el subjects_array es una lista que contiene 7 datos, esos los quiero meter en la columna A de mi hoja de cálculo

Answer (score 1):

Existe un módulo de python que se llama `pandas` que está diseñado para trabajar con `DataFrames`, un tipo de objeto que podrías visualizar como una hoja de Excel. Convirtiendo la lista a este `DataFrame`, simplemente tendrías que hacer algo así:

```py
# l es la lista a convertir
df = pandas.DataFrame(l)
df.to_excel("nombre_fichero_excel")
```

Tienes la documentación [aquí](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Comment: Estoy usando openpyxl para hacer el llenado, desgraciadamente no es opcional :( sé que utilizando DataFrames es más sencillo

Comment: Entonces te sugiero que sigas [estos pasos](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-writing-excel-file-using-openpyxl-module/), pues no conozco en profundidad ese API

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta era bastante simple, sólo tenía que sumarle uno a mi auxiliar debido a que estaba sobre escribiendo la celda que pertenecía a mi útimo indice de mi lista... quedaría así

```
    celda = 8
    contador = 0
    aux = 0    
    for materia in self.subjects_array:
        contador += 1
        hola = celda + contador
        datos['A{0}'.format(hola)] = materia
        aux = hola + 1
    datos['A{0}'.format(aux)] = 'Inglés'
    datos['B{0}'.format(aux)] = 'De acuerdo a coordinación de inglés'
    datos['C{0}'.format(aux)] = 'De acuerdo a coordinación de inglés'
    datos['D{0}'.format(aux)] = 'De acuerdo a coordinación de inglés'
    datos['E{0}'.format(aux)] = 'De acuerdo a coordinación de inglés'
    datos['F{0}'.format(aux)] = 'De acuerdo a coordinación de inglés'
    datos['G{0}'.format(aux)] = 'De acuerdo a coordinación de inglés'
```

Ya que uso el auxiliar para anexar una materia extra ;)